# Apex - Getting System.UnexpectedException while iterating over JSON

Tags: apex, gack

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
    "properties":[
        {
            "isVisible":true
        },
        {
            "isOverlapping":false
        }
     ]
 }
```

In apex code, I am iterating over the same JSON object:

```
for (Object obj : requestObj.properties) {

//some code

}
```

The code saves successfully. It gives me the following error when I try to invoke this from javascript(the error is caught in the salesforce developer console):

> FATAL_ERROR System.UnexpectedException: Salesforce System Error: 1574064081-423898 (225376621) (225376621)

Upon debugging, the exception is thrown at line where for loop begins. I am calling the method through a remote action and my request is automatically mapped to the type of input the remote action takes.

Comment: I am calling the method through a remote action and my request is automatically mapped to the type of input the remote action takes.

Comment: Can you actually add the `Type` of object that `requestObj` is and its definition?

Answer (score 1):

Open a case with support and provide as much detail about reproduction as you can. You've run into a gack. R&D should already be working on it or have it in their queue. Note that Salesforce specifically calls out that the error is **not your fault** in describing what a gack is.

> ## [What Is A Gack?](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html)
>
> If you’ve been around Salesforce long enough, you have probably encountered a screen that looks like this one here:
>
> [image: gack]
>
> What you are looking at is what we call a GACK. A gack is our blue screen of death, our frowny Mac icon, our “the number you have reached is no longer in service”, our “Jedediah has died of dysentery”. A gack is what happens when an error got thrown within our application and we didn’t catch it and handle it.
>
> What this means is that it’s not your fault. It’s ours. That’s why we apologize in that message. Sorry!
>
> This friendly message is the above-water portion of a huge iceberg of functionality. The numbers you see are part of an elaborate system for efficiently bringing these events to the attention of R&D. This post will help you understand that system, and how you can help us in getting you running safely. (Hint: steer away from icebergs.)

Comment: Should I open a case with Salesforce?

Comment: Yep, that's your best bet when you get a gack.

Comment: @kanika - and be sure you have a super simple reproducible test case that can be readily performed by support.